# What's the difference between "Obscurus" and "Obscurials"?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them, obscurus

What's the difference between "Obscurus" and "Obscurials"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An [Obscurus](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Obscurus) is a type of powerful magical parasite that forms when a wizard or witch suppresses their magical ability. An [Obscurial](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Obscurial) is the person whose body is a host for the Obscurus.